# Ruby On Rails - Namespacing Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am encountering an issue in namespacing models in rails.
I have these models in my app

```
Request
Food
Clothing
Request::Food
Request::Clothing
```

I passed a namespaced model like `Request::Food` as an argument but the function still calls for `Food` where it should have been calling for the name-spaced model `Request::Food`.
I tried updating the namespacing like `Requests::Food` and it works.

Is there any particular reason for this matter? Is there any way I could retain this namespacing `Request::Food`, `Request::Clothing`?

Example:

```
 def authorize(resource)
    policy_object = "#{resource.name}Policy".classify.constantize
 end
```

`authorize(Request::Food)` returns `FoodPolicy` instead of `RequestFoodPolicy`

Comment: Could you share a bit of an example? Usually rails is dynamically typed, so functions don't really care about what type the argument you provide is

Comment: Could this be the issue? https://rubystyle.guide/#namespace-definition

Comment: I updated it @BenjaminScharbau and added a sample.

Comment: Is this devise? I also understand that both `Request::Food` and `Food` are supposed to use the same table in your database?

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau It's not devise, I'm implementing some kind of design pattern with my application.
Yes, `Request::Food` inherits `Food`.

Comment: How do you retrieve your food object from the database before you pass it to the authorize method?

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau I just passed `Request::Food` class to authorize method.

Answer (score 0):

While namespacing models, you have to take care of few things -

1. you need to **explicitly** name your table as `model b` will point to `table b` but `model a:b` will **not** point to `table b`, you have to mention that too.
2. Make sure you dont miss change `a:b model` where ever needed as `model b` and `model a:b` are different now, better go with new name like `model a:b` and `model c`.

So your model should be like  -

```
class Request::Food < ApplicationRecord
  ## this should not be foods
  self.table_name = 'food_requests'

  ## instance method
  def get_food;end
```

you need to call `Request::Food.first.get_food`

to verify this, visit `rails console` and hit Request::Food.new to see what is the table getting hit.

Comment: The thing is `Request::Food` should also point to `Food`. I just needed to make a name-spaced resource for me to have a dynamic function to also access name-spaced patterns like `Request::Food::CreateService`, `Request::FoodPolicy` and etc.

Comment: Rails usually would expect the table to be named `request_foods`. If created by `rails generate model Request::Food` the migration should take care of that automatically.

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau What I actually did here is an STI where `Request::Food` inherited from `Food`

`class Request::Food < Food`

Comment: if its an STI, It will always call food unless you use a TYPE. Hope you get it @SidneyJohnDiongzon